# Java: non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, equation, quadratic

```
  package lab10;

  import java.util.*;
  public class Lab10 {

  class QuadraticEquation{

   double a,b,c;

   QuadraticEquation(){
     Random number1 = new Random();
     a = (int) (number1.nextDouble() * 8 + 1.0);

     Random number2 = new Random();
     b = (int) (number2.nextDouble() * 8 + 1.0);

     Random number3 = new Random();
     c = (int) (number3.nextDouble() * 8 + 1.0);


   }
   double getA(){

       return a;
   }
   double getB(){

       return b;
   }
   double getC(){      

       return c;
   }
   double getDiscriminant(){
       double discriminant;

       discriminant = (Math.pow(b, 2)- 4 *(a *c));
       return discriminant;
     }
   }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    QuadraticEquation equation = new QuadraticEquation(); //<---- error

    System.out.println("Three randomized coefficients are: ");
    System.out.println("a = " + equation.getA());
    System.out.println("b = " + equation.getB());
    System.out.println("c = " + equation.getC());

}
  }
```

I've read a couple of posts here on stackoverflow about this error but even after reading them I don't seem to really understand why I'm getting it. I'm referencing a previous project and I don't understand why I cant declare **QuadraticEquation equation = new QuadraticEquation()**

Here is the project I'm referencing:

```
   package InClass05;

   public class TestSimpleSquare {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    SimpleSquare square1 = new SimpleSquare();
    System.out.println("The area of the square of side lengths " + square1.length + " is " + square1.getArea());
    System.out.println("The perimeter of the square of side lengths " + square1.length + " is " + square1.getPerimeter());
    System.out.println("The diagonal of the square of side lengths " + square1.length + " is " + square1.getDiagonal());

    System.out.println("");
    SimpleSquare square2 = new SimpleSquare(25);
    System.out.println("The area of the square of side lengths " + square2.length + " is " + square2.getArea());
    System.out.println("The perimeter of the square of side lengths " + square2.length + " is " + square2.getPerimeter());
    System.out.println("The diagonal of the square of side lengths " + square2.length + " is " + square2.getDiagonal());

    System.out.println("");
    square2.length = 500;
    System.out.println("The area of the square of side lengths " + square2.length + " is " + square2.getArea());
    System.out.println("The perimeter of the square of side lengths " + square2.length + " is " + square2.getPerimeter());
    System.out.println("The diagonal of the square of side lengths " + square2.length + " is " + square2.getDiagonal());


}
  }
  class SimpleSquare{
  double length;

   SimpleSquare(){
    length = 10;
}

SimpleSquare(double newlength){
    length = newlength;
}

double getArea(){
    return length * length;
}

double getPerimeter(){
    return length + length + length + length;
}

double getDiagonal(){
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(length, 2) + Math.pow(length, 2));
}
void setlength(double newlength){
    length = newlength;
}
 }
```

In this one I'm able to declare **SimpleSquare square1 = new SimpleSquare();**
I don't get why I can't do that in the project I'm working on now.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
QuadraticEquation equation = new Lab10().new QuadraticEquation();
```

because `QuadraticEquation` is inner class

Answer (score 0):

You could add the word `static` to make your class static:

`static class QuadraticEquation`

Without this your class in inner for `Lab10` so it should be attached to the enclosing instance. Usually inner classes are created inside the members of the class.

It compiles after this:

```
Three randomized coefficients are: 
a = 5.0
b = 7.0
c = 3.0
```

Comment: I see. But how come it works in my reference project without declaring it as a static class. I was able to do SimpleSquare square1 = new SimpleSquare(); without getting an error.

Comment: There it is defined on a different level, not inside your class. This is called a package level. These two cases are very different from Java's point of view. `SimpleSquare` case is like it is defined in a separate file.

Comment: @DeathWish your class QuadraticEquation is defined inside the class Lab10. Your class SimpleSquare is not inside another class (you close the TestSimpleSquare class before you define it)

Answer (score 0):

`QuadraticEquation` is defined as an inner class within the class `Lab10`.  As such, it cannot be created except within an instance of the outer class, unless you change it to be a static inner class:

```
static class QuadraticEquation{
...
}
```

Or if you need it to be non-static, you can create an instance of the outer class when you create the inner class:

```
QuadraticEquation equation = new Lab10().new QuadraticEquation();
```

After a momentary puzzlement mirroring your own, I see that in your other situation, the class `SimpleSquare` is just not an inner class.  It is another class at top level.

Java allows you to define multiple classes at the same level in the same file as long as only one of them is public.

The difference is the (possibly accidental) different placement of an end brace!

Comment: I see. But how come it works in my previous project without declaring it as a static class. I was able to do **SimpleSquare square1 = new SimpleSquare();** without getting an error.